# Question about central spatial moments

Tags: image-processing, statistics, maximum-likelihood-estimation, probability

> - Spatial moment 
>     $$
>   m_{pq} = \sum_{(x, y)\ \in \mathbb R} x^p y^q I(x, y)
>   $$
> - The order of each moment is $p+q$.
> - Central moment 
>     $$
>   \mu_{pq} = \sum_{(x, y)\ \in \mathbb R} (x - \bar x)^p (x - \bar y)^q I(x, y)
>   $$

What transformation are the central spatial moments $\mu_{pq}$ invariant to that the spatial moments mpq are not?

Comment: Do you have any idea on the solution? It looks like homework

Comment: @Maximilian Matthé I think the answer would be one of the property of translation invariant ,scale invariant and rotation invariant in central moment, but I am not sure which one is not invariant to spatial moments

Answer (score 1):

It removes the mean, hence invariant to addition of a constant.